# MySQL - SELECT default value if null

Tags: php, mysql

Here's my query that I'm working with:

```
SELECT (COUNT(`pass` = 0) / COUNT((`pass` = 0) + (`pass` = 1))) AS `PassRate` from `quiz_results`
```

Where I'm trying to get a percentage of people who have passed the quiz, however the issue is that if nobody as passed the quiz, then `NULL` is returned. I'm trying to figure out how to return `0` in the event of `NULL`.

I've tried using `ISNULL` however I didn't have any luck.

The other issue I'm running into is that if nobody has failed the quiz, the value is always zero. So my two problems are as follows:

- Convert NULL to 0.
- Return 100 when `COUNT(`pass`=0)` returns 0.

Unfortunately I'm not all that great with SQL and I'm a bit stumped. I'm accessing MySQL through PHP. I added that in here, because I don't know if it changes anything.

I'm using The SQL installed with XAMPP (Comes with PhpMyAdmin)

Comment: Post your best attempt.

Answer (score 1):

First, you don't want `COUNT()`, you want `SUM()`:

```
SELECT (SUM(`pass` = 0) / SUM((`pass` = 0) + (`pass` = 1))) AS `PassRate` 
FROM `quiz_results`
```

The expressions `COUNT(pass = 0)` and `COUNT(pass = 1)` always return *exactly* the same number, and this is equivalent to `COUNT(pass)`.  `COUNT()` is just looking at whether or not the expression is `NULL`.

Then, you can replace this with `AVG()`, probably:

```
SELECT AVG(pass = 0)  -- Should this be `pass = 1` ?
FROM quiz_results;
```

And, if you still get unwanted `NULL` values:

```
SELECT COALESCE(AVG(pass = 0), 0)  -- Should this be `pass = 1` ?
FROM quiz_results;
```